# Voltage Doubler Capacitor Values

Tags: rf

When designing a voltage doubler at RF frequencies...

Should you pick Capacitor values that makes C1 and C2 impedance 50 ohms ?

[image]

[image: From Wiki]

Comment: If you're dealing with RF, use a capacitor to resonate that secondary transformer winding.

Comment: I'll take note of that, but the picture was a bad choice, my input source is an antenna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The impedance of a voltage multiplier isn't just the impedance of the capacitors.  Because of the multiplication effect, the impedance of the multiplier is a multiple of the capacitor impedance.  It can be calculated using the [formula for the impedance of a Cockcroft-Walton multiplier](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/diode-capacitors-volts-pt7) with the number of stages set to 1.

The impedance of a Cockcroft-Walton multiplier is given by:

$$\frac {1}{2 \pi fC} (4n^3 + 3n^2 - n)$$

Where:

- \$n\$ is the number of stages (1 for a Greinacher doubler.)
- \$C\$ is the capacitance in farads.
- \$f\$ is the frequency in hertz of your input signal.

For a single stage, that works out to 6 times the impedance of a single capacitor.

The impedance the antenna "sees" should be the sum of the multiplier impedance and the load impedance.

If you want maximum power from the antenna, then you would try to make the total impedance (multiplier and load) match the antenna impedance.

---

Pretty much all my experience with voltage doublers is at low frequencies and low voltages.  RF and impedance matching aren't exactly my strong suit.

That said, I **have** built a multiplier for detecting cellphone and WiFi signals.  It was completely passive - powered entirely from the antenna.  It could light an LED to indicate a  cellphone transmitting at a "range" of a couple of centimeters.

Things you'll want to keep in mind:

1. Use diodes rated to operate at your frequency (or rather, frequency range.)
2. Use diodes that have a **low** forward voltage.  Germanium diodes aren't usable up to GHz frequencies - they give up somewhere over 100MHz.  The forward voltages varies with current.  Lower current, lower forward voltage.  Look for diodes whose datasheets give you a curve relating forward voltage to current.  I used a pile of [BAT63](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BAT63SERIES-DS-v01_01-en.pdf?fileId=db3a304314dca38901151817843c0df4) diodes since I wanted to detect up to 2.4GHz.
3. At high frequencies, you'll have to pay attention to the parasitic inductance of the capacitors.  If the capacitor datasheet doesn't mention the inductance or doesn't cover your frequency range then you should find a different capacitor that does.

I'm sure there are others here who can give you better advice on the RF parts, and on how to decide whether to match the antenna impedance to the multiplier impedance.  Corrections and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Using ADS I built the circuit and determined the circuit Impedance using their S11 to Z_in formula now I can match the antenna to the circuit...i'll see how it goes